# Using ADO.Net Core With Models, I want to Display Data From Different Relational Tables But It Gives Me Some Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datareader, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an error in the code below. When I use it for one table it works fine, But it doesn't work for relational tables.

**Method for displaying all records:**

```
public List<AdminUserRegisterModel> GetAll()
    {
        List<AdminUserRegisterModel> List = new List<AdminUserRegisterModel>();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_admin_user_search_all", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader dr;

            connection.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           // while(dr.HasRows)
            //{
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    AdminUserRegisterModel obj = new AdminUserRegisterModel();
                    obj.adminUsers.adminId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["adminId"]);
                    obj.adminUsers.adminName = Convert.ToString(dr["adminName"]);
                    obj.adminUsers.adminEmail = Convert.ToString(dr["adminEmail"]);
                    obj.adminUsers.adminPassword = Convert.ToString(dr["adminPassword"]);
                    obj.adminUsers.adminStatus = Convert.ToInt32(dr["adminStatus"]);
                    obj.adminUsers.joinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["adminJoinDate"]);
                    // AdminUserProfile table
                    obj.adminProfiles.adminProfileId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["profileId"]);
                    obj.adminProfiles.firstName = Convert.ToString(dr["firstName"]);
                    obj.adminProfiles.lastName = Convert.ToString(dr["lastName"]);
                    obj.adminProfiles.cnic = Convert.ToString(dr["cnic"]);
                    obj.adminProfiles.profileImg = Convert.ToString(dr["profileImg"]);
                    obj.adminProfiles.adminId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["adminId"]);

                    List.Add(obj);
                }
            //}

            if (!dr.IsClosed)
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
            connection.Close();

            return List;
        }
        catch
        {
            connection.Close();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Controller method:**

```
// Display All Records
    public ActionResult Display()
    {
        repObj = new AdminUserRegisterRepository();
        return View(repObj.GetAll());
    }
```

**Model class:**

```
public class AdminUserRegisterModel
{
    public adminUser adminUsers { get; set; }
    public admin_profile adminProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

---

It gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you checked for exceptions in `GetAll()`? I see it returns null, in case of exception, and this can cause NullReferenceException inside `@foreach(var item in Model)` from the screenshot.

Comment: Why It Returns Null? How i can Solve This ?
I Have Used This Stored Procedure......

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_admin_user_search_all]
 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT adminUser.*, admin_profile.* FROM adminUser 
    INNER JOIN admin_profile ON adminUser.adminId = admin_profile.adminId;
END

Comment: No I didnt Check for Exception......
I m New, Please Help Me out.... #Johan

Comment: Try to return `new List<AdminUserRegisterModel>()` instead of `null` in the catch block.

Comment: http://imgur.com/eVnetxl

Comment: It Works But No Data Shows @Johan
Look at this Image  https://i.imgsafe.org/41f47313d1.png
Now Shows This after Return List in Catch block

catch
{
     connection.close();
     return List;
}

Comment: My GettAll Method Is Not Working Correctly, Please Tell Me How To solve This.....
WHen it Start Read Data, It Throws An Exception....

Comment: Anyone Here To Help Me out?

Comment: Please Help Me Out

Comment: No One Help Me on This issue :(